# Calling Another Method in the Fragment

Tags: android

I want to call another method in the Fragment but if i use the main_activity i have to write this type of the my function.

**TempratureFragment.java** //I have a error

```
   adapter =new ViewPageAdapter(getFragmentManager(),arrayFragment,arrayTittle);
```

**ViewPAgeAdapter.java** //Class

```
public ViewPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm,ArrayList<Fragment> arrayFragment, ArrayList<String> arrayTittle) {
        super(fm);

        this.arrayFragment =arrayFragment;
        this.arrayTittle=arrayTittle;

    }
```

How can i getting the function in my fragment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your response. But i solved to my problem.
If we want to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` in the fragment, 
Firstly we have to change library to:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

And we have to change all java class which is include Fragment, FragmentManager and FragmentPageAdapter libraries with these:

```
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
```

And if we come back our fragment and now we can use the `getSupportFragmentManager()  with the getActivity().

```
 adapter =new ViewPageAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),arrayFragment,arrayTittle);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity do this

```
((YourFragment) adapter.getItem(position)).yourMethod();
```